# How make a join table like bellow in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

Helllo, i want to do a join between tow tables in laravel, but if table B has no rows query return null.
What i want is like this.

```
table A

id user_id description
1    1      something
2    1       apple
3    2       cherry

table B

user_id post_id vote
(with no records initial)

result table

    id user_id description post_id  vote
    1    1      something    null   null
    2    1       apple       null   null
    3    2       cherry      null   null
```

How can i do that?
Thank you in advance and I apologize for the worse English.

Comment: Make hasMany relation in User model. and fetch $user->posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [leftJoin](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause)

```
 DB::table("tableA")->leftJoin("tableB","tableA.user_id",'=','tableB.user_id')
           ->select(["tableA.id as id",'tableA.user_id as user_id','description','post_id','vote'])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, it was perfect :D

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage eloquent relations to get the desired output

```php
Assume Table A is represented by ModelA and Table B is represented by ModelB

class ModelA extends Model
{
    //Get all related ModelB records
    public function kids()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelB::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}

class ModelB extends Model
{
    //Get the ModelA record to which the ModelB record belongs
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ModelA::class, 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Now you can get all ModelB (related) records for a ModelA record anywhere

```php
$modelA = ModelA::with('kids')->first();

$modelA->kids //These records will hold values from Table B
```

Or using QueryBuilder

```php
$rows = DB::table('TableA')
    ->leftJoin('TableB', 'TableA.user_id', '=', 'TableB.user_id')
    ->select('id', 'TableA.user_id', 'description', 'post_id', 'vote');
```

Eloquent or Query Builder is a choice to make

Answer (score 0):

Let assume Table A is User model and Table B is Post model.
Eloquent query:

```
$users = User::leftJoin('posts', function($join) {
      $join->on('users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id');
    })
    ->whereNull('posts.user_id')
    ->first([
        'users.id',
        'users.description',
        'posts.id',
        'posts.vote'
    ]);
```